# Dynamic class initialisation doesn't work in 2GMP

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-apex, second-generation-packaging, 2gmp

I want to use dependency injection to detect if descendant package is installed in addition to inherited package and modify the behaviour of inherited package to depend on class from descendant package.

I use `Type.forName()` method for that and it works just fine on the scratch org (both namespaced and unpackaged) but it doesn't work in subscriber class.

This is strange, but when I query or get information for custom object from the descendant package I can use local name without a problem. However, when I use `Type.forName` it throws a null pointer exception even when I try to prepend the shared namespace between packages or use overload version with two parameters, this doesn't help

I tried the following options:

Option 1.

```
Type.forName('ClassName').newInstance(); // <= Null Pointer error here
```

Option 2.

```
Type.forName('Namespace.ClassName').newInstance(); // <= Null Pointer error here as well
```

Option 3.

```
Type.forName('Namespace', 'ClassName').newInstance(); // <= Null Pointer error here as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only change which has to be made was adding @namespaceAccessible annotation to the `ClassName` in the descendant package.

```
@namespaceAccessible
public with sharing class ClassName extends AncestorClassName{
}
```

My prior understanding was that only classes from the ancestor package need this annotation, but looks like this was a false assumption